# Facebook comment box not displaying

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have project in wordpress with magazine theme. I noticed the facebook comment box was not displaying on single.php page. when I viewed through 'View Page Source' the code was present even space was left for comment box between the article and advertisement. 
I checked css for display:none or any other thing that might have caused but no solution yet.
I am getting that div as 
where data-href is coming as "./"  Please help.

Comment: Have you tried including js sdk and fb-root element in your markup?

Comment: yes all that has been added. Recently we migrated to different server(flywheel).Is that posing a problem?

Comment: You can check console on developer tools for all javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Working sample:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:comments href="http://stackoverflow.com/" numposts="5" colorscheme="light"></fb:comments>
</body>
</html>
```